# Generate auto transaction id from database mySQL PHP

Tags: php, transactions, auto-generate

I am trying to generate the transaction number while I am inserting the data in my database through PHP.
I want to generate the sequence transaction id, so that I am doing the below SQL.
I am counting the ID column and add +1 value for new inserts.
but when I have a bulk insert it will not for after a single entry and showing different transaction id.

I want the `ALFABHETs` will always constant and after the number will continuously run.
if the number will be reached then, it will automatically become 3 to 4 digits.

For example, the number will start from **MG001**. If MG999 then it will becomes to **MG1000**,**MG1001**,**MG1002** etc

```
#table_name: table1

ID | transactionID  
------------------
1  | MG001
2  | MG001
3  | MG003
4  | MG004
5  | MG004
6  | MG001

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $transactionCode = 'MG' . $data['ID'] + 1;
    }
} else {
    $transactionCode = 'MG001' . '1';
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. You compute the `$transactionCode` based on the `ID` in the database, why does this pose a problem with bulk inserts? I assume that `ID` is your [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) index?

Comment: This looks prone to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). If you get two requests at the same time, both requests could theoretically get the same transaction id.

Answer (score 0):

Your query loads the record with the highest ID, which is a single record and adds 1 to it if found. If there was no record, then you use `'MG0011'` as value. Since you have a single value, if you put that into your bulk insert's code, then it will be duplicated. So you should load transactionID (and not ID), strip the MG or whatever prefix from it and add 1 to it. Example:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $transactionCode = (int)substr($data['transactionID'], 2) + 1;
    }
} else {
    $transactionCode = 1;
}
```

The code above generates a starting point and does not care (yet) about the format that you intend to use. Now, let's implement a function that generates the code as you need it:

```
function generateTransactionCode($input, $prefix = 'MG') {
    while (strlen($input) < 3) $input = '0'.$input;
    return $prefix.$input;
}
```

And now let's generate a bulk insert command (I assume that you `auto_increment` the `ID`):

```
$sql = 'insert into table1(transactionID) values';
$values = [];
for ($index = 0; $index < 5; $index++) { //we insert 5 values in this example
    $values[]='('.generateTransactionCode($transactionCode + $index).')';
}
$sql .= implode(',', $values);
//Execute the insert
```

It's more tricky to do that with insert select statements. If you need to do that, then you will need to use [row_number](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/).

Comment: this is a very confusing answer.. can I do one function? > fetch transaction id from table if exist retun but how to create this code

Comment: this this right way to do this please help to collaborate `https://paiza.io/projects/e/TNwmwVB9rM4KGYrnltejow?theme=ambiance`

Comment: @ShubhamNagar you can put everything into a function, but it's not advisable, because the idea behind creating a function for each atomic feature is to separate concerns. When I generate a transaction code, the goal is to make sure that I do not have to do the insertion. Other features may need to generate transaction code without the insertion. So small and concise functions is the way to go.

Comment: how to achieve the goal ?

Comment: @ShubhamNagar I can see the code you have shared in the link you have given. That code is mining out a number and adding one to 1 so that you get a new code. So, the question is: what is the exact blocker that you face now trying to apply my solution? Let's remove the blockers one-by-one.